# Web push notifications in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-push

I have created web push notifications and they work in Firefox ok (service worker is registered, subscription created, subscription data stored, using subscription data notification is sent ok). I have tried the same in Chrome and Opera, but nothing happens. I tried to debug, and after I send push notification, browser receives it, executes code, but nothing happens. There are no errors, code runs till the end. Service worker code is the following:

```
'use strict';
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('Push started');
  const promiseChain = self.registration.showNotification('Hello, World.');

  event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
  console.log('Push finished');
});
```

I see in console 'Push started' and 'Push finished'. Server uses https. Any ideas, what can be wrong?

Comment: I have no idea about how its work in Firefox, so I might sound stupid, but did you remember to ask the user for permission to send them notifications? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/

Comment: Yes, I ask for permission to send notifications before subscribing. When I check permissions, it shows notifications are allowed. Possibly that's because I ask for permission in web-page, not in service worker.  It happens like this:
function askp() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const permissionResult = Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {
      resolve(result);
    });
     if (permissionResult) {
      permissionResult.then(resolve, reject);
    }
  })
  .then(function(permissionResult) {
  // get subscription
  });
}

Answer (score 1):

A assume you have a development domain with no https. Google Chrome only sends notifications when running with configured SSL.

How to bypass: For local development you can launch Chrome with the `unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` option.

```
open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome \
     --args \
     --user-data-dir=$HOME \
     --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://your-insecure-domain.dev \
```

Answer (score 0):

I have configured SSL in my application and running it with https.Till i am not getting any notifications in chrome, but in firefox and edge its working.

Answer (score 0):

After a short research I came to know that notification was blocked for chrome from system settings on macbook. Enabling notification for chrome from system settings works for me!

Try to enable for your browser and check again