# Push notifications not working in Chrome for angular-pwa-course

Tags: push-notification, angular6, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I need desktop notification. So I have integrated The Angular PWA series course i.e. https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/. I am able to get push notification in Firefox but in chrome I am not getting any push notifications.

Operating System: Linux
Node Version:10.8.0
web-push Version:3.2.5
Chrome :Version 72.0.3626.119

Comment: A assume you have a development domain with no https. Google Chrome only send notifications when running with configured SSL. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134261/web-push-notifications-in-chrome/56262187#56262187

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web push notifications in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134261/web-push-notifications-in-chrome)